# List files in exited container

Tags: docker

Is there an easy way to check what files were produced after container exits?

I saw recommendations to rewrite `Dockerfile` and add `ls` commands to it, but that's not the easy way for me.

**UPDATE**: I was using `VOLUME` directive inside `Dockerfile` and `docker diff` doesn't show changes there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `docker diff container_name`. This inspect changes to files or directories on a container filesystem.

It shows something like this.

```
A /usr/local/lib/python2.7/email 
C /usr/local/lib/python2.7/email/mime 
D /usr/local/lib/python2.7/email/mime/audio.pyc
```

`A`: A file or directory was added

`C`: A file or directory was changed

`D`: A file or directory was deleted

Hope this helps, good luck!