# Files in dir that is also a VOLUME?

Tags: docker

I am just curious. To [List files in exited container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365849/list-files-in-exited-container) I can use `docker diff`, but if target directory is also a volume, such as:

```
RUN mkdir /target
VOLUME /target
```

Then `docker diff` won't show anything. Does that mean that `/target` is left empty after container exits? How can I check the contents of that `/target` in exited container?

Comment: What's your host OS?

Comment: @Robert Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

`docker diff` doesn't show any changes because this command inspect changes to files or directories **on a container filesystem.**

A volume, referring to Docker documentation, is this:

> A data volume is a specially-designated directory within one or more containers that bypasses the Union File System.

This explains why `docker diff` doesn't show changes inside a volume.

> Does that mean that /target is left empty after container exits?

No. Data volumes persist even if the container is deleted.

> How can I check the contents of that /target in exited container?

You can find container volumes using `docker inspect` command.

`docker inspect container_name`

The output will be something like this, where `Source` specifies location of the volume in the host machine.

```
...
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Name": "fac362...80535",
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/fac362...80535/_data",
        "Destination": "/webapp",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": ""
    }
]
...
```

> I do mkdir /target before making it a volume. So what happens to the contents of this dir if it already exists inside of container in this case

If the dir existed previously, contents are copied into the new created volume. So, if you make your directory a volume, you'll not lose your changes.

Comment: But `/target` does exist inside of container, because I explicitly create it.

Comment: `/target` exists in your container, but is a link to a folder in your `/var/lib/docker/volumes...` in your host machine.

Comment: So what happens with dir that I created in this place then?

Comment: I'm not undestanding what you're asking. `/target` directory inside the container and `/var/lib/docker/volumes...` are "same" directories, so, if you delete `/target` inside your container your data will be in `/var/lib/docker/volumes...`

Comment: I do `mkdir /target` before making it a volume. So what happens to the contents of this dir if it already exists inside of container in this case?